# Update, add, remove plugins, themes or wordpress behind load balancer

Tags: updates, server, server-load

I am running wordpress on two identical servers.
Both sit behind a load balancer.
Both use the same database.

How am I supposed to do things like update a plugin or wordpress?

My current thought is to:

1. Disconnect one of the servers from the LB - So I know which one I'm working with.
2. Perform necessary change (eg: update plugin) via dashboard.
3. Copy necessary directory from the active server (eg: `plugins/some_plugin`) and replace that file on the inactive server. (Since changes were already made to the DB, I don't want to use the Dashboard to update the other server).

Is this the way to update/remove/add plugins/wordpress?

I thought this would be a common way to set up wordpress, but I didn't find much documentation about it. Is there a preferred set up?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use the WordPress admin area to do this, you'll need to find a server oriented way of doing it, likely using version control, composer or WP CLI, I'd suggest a combination of the first with one of the latter two

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a little more detail? Since all answers seem pretty involved, is it best to just have wordpress on 1 server? Traffic isn't high. I am using two servers because my main site has 2 servers (this is a subdirectory installation).

Comment: It's an involved subject, there's no easy fix installing a WP plugin or checking a box here or there, or a simple command. You're veering very close to this being a best practices question and it being mostly opinions and thus out of scope. The crux of your issue is that you have a *deployment* or *provisioning* problem, right now you're doing it manually. There are lots of ways of automating that, and there is no right or wrong answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a fantastic question - I've personally never run into this before, but here's what I'd try, assuming:

- you have an image of a server that you've been using to spin up new instances
- you're using a CDN and cloud storage for images and uploads (rather than having a local uploads folder)

With those two assumptions, it means you can spin up and spin down instances of the server without worrying about data loss - the files and config between each server are identical.

- Spin up a new instance of your server, but don't add it to the load balancer
- point your hosts file to the IP of the instance
- update the plugin on the instance, make sure everything is working as you expect
- create an image of the updated server
- spin up one more instance based on the updated image
- point the LB at the new instances

This is a bit of a painful process, and I think next would also look into automated deployment tools, such as Capistrano, or maybe a service like Deploy.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain "point your hosts file to the IP of the instance"? Are you basically suggesting creating two new instances every time and removing the old two?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. [modifying your hosts file](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/) allows you to override any DNS records and just tell your local computer that *that* server hosts *this* website.

Comment: I'm leaning towards using your solution. It still seems a little involved. What is the problem with the solution I suggested in the question?

Comment: Not anything dramatic, this is just how I would do it if I were in your shoes. Two reasons to not do it your way: (1) you're removing an instance from your load balancer to make modifications to it - the reason you have two instances is because of traffic. What happens if your traffic scales up and you need 3 or 4 instances to handle the traffic? Will you take all of them offline? (2) making changes to files live on production is less than ideal. AKA "cowboy coding". Even plugin upgrades are a bit iffy. What happens when an upgrade breaks the site?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I much prefer first testing on local environment and then deploying the change to production (this is how I will be handling all the code I change in my child theme). Are you suggesting not updating plugins or the core? I didn't know this was an option. I'm new to WordPress. I thought updates were necessary? Is this not the case? I am new to WP and PHP, so if you have any other suggestions on a workflow, I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: I have low traffic, the main reason I have 2 instances is in case a server goes down. Eventually, perhaps, traffic might be higher.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting not updating plugins at all; just not updating them on a live production site. Most of the time I use git or composer to handle plugin updates: I'll run the update on a staging environment, test to make sure everything's good, then use git to commit the changes, ssh to the production site, and pull the updated code. I rarely ever use the plugin update button in the WP admin area.

Comment: Isn't it possible for updates to make changes to the DB as well?

Comment: yes, it is possible, though rare. Which is why I originally answered the question the way I did. The database will get updated that way. The way I normally do it, does not usually involve multiple environments. If a specific plugin does do db updates, I check that it works locally then run the same update in production - but as you've pointed out, that probably wouldn't work correctly in a load balanced server.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be done in few steps

1. replicate the DB (in case you do not already have one).
2. remove one server from the LB, change its config to point to the "new" DB.
3. connect to the admin area only to that server (define in your localhosts file the IP or any other way and do the upgrade.).
4. In the LB turn the other server off and the upgraded one on.
5. update the plugin on the other server (basically it is enough to update the code)
6. connect the other server to the "new" DB
7. change the LB configuration to enable the other server.

As this is not an extremely quick procedure you should either minimize the number of plugins you use as pure plugins, or try to upgrade as many as possible at the same time.

(I wrote plugin, but it applies to themes and core as well)

Answer (score 0):

I have been in this same situation for many years -- 3 servers behind a load balancer.  Different disk subsystems.  Shared database.  I actually found this question by searching for some way to simplify management.  What I have been doing (and what has been working fine) for many years is the following:

1. Make sure that I have automatic backups of everything (database and files) ... just in case.  I have never needed them, but that is always a prerequisite.
2. Login to the WP admin console and note what server you are connecting to, if possible
3. Update wordpress and plugins using the normal UI methods
4. Login to the server in question (and if you could not tell which it was using some feature of your infrastructure, look at the time stamps of the plugin files that you just updated).
5. Copy the wordpress directory tree to the other server(s)
6. Backup the old WP directories there and replace with the new directories.

This has never failed.  However, it is not 100% recommended as WP running on the severs that are not yet upgraded could have issues during the upgrade due to software or database inconsistencies. Usually the process is very quick anyway.

The best solution is to do the above, but by taking the servers you are not updating out of service first and updating them before re-enabling them on your load balancer.  I suppose it is up to you where you fit on the "quick and easy" vs "risk" curve for your blog.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers seem to be based on the assumption that you are *only* running/updating your website on a remote server; and as such, some of the solutions seem very complicated. I have two sites that both run behind load balancers - one with 2 servers, and one with 4; both of which are scalable to as many servers as required. Both of these sites are maintained & updated with a couple of clicks using a local build, Git and Jenkins.

I have a functional copy of the sites on `localhost` running under `XAMPP`. The databases aren't identical, but the file structure is. I also have a private BitBucket account and a `.gitignore` to ignore things like my local `wp-config` and the `/uploads/` folder (which I don't want or need to sync with the server).

Whenever there's a plugin update, I update it through Wordpress on my `localhost` as normal. Once it's done, I open up my Git client and push the changes to BitBucket.

On the server, I have a [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) service that is set to build from my BitBucket source to the live site. I click *Build*, wait a couple of minutes, and it's all done. Jenkins builds to all servers, and there's rsync available to make sure everything is simpatico.

So my entire update process is **Update local** -> **Git push** -> **Jenkins build**

This is reliant on you having a `localhost` or other controllable build that you can push with Git, but once it's set up and running, updating your load-balanced Wordpress site becomes incredibly easy.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since this was answered, but I have some thoughts that I thought I would add - having had to take care of this same situation several times over the last few years. It involved several extremely high traffic and high visibility sites that were load balanced with three to four nodes each.

The first thing I did was I wrote a linux script that essentially runs as a cron job twice a day. It checks for available core and plugin updates using the `wp-cli` tool. It runs on each server that is a node of the LB. It worked (at the time) in conjunction with a plugin that could limit what plugins were updated automatically.

The most recent thing I did was having a staging server that we accessed for content/code changes. The changes on that environment were then synced to whatever live nodes were active at the time. This was done in AWS EC2 instances using RDS for DB. It allowed for relatively seamless updating. We had to do a bit of customization around the DB push in order to preserve production data which had not been synced to our staging environment.